# How to restrict user to create namespace in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

Say i have a k8s cluster.

I would like to restrict user to create their own namespace. And only allow admin to create namespace.

I am trying to use of cluster role rules:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: my-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["v1"]
  resources: ["namespaces"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

But I found user still can create namespace. Any solution to do so?

Comment: Share the Role/ClusteRole and ClusterRoleBinding/Rolebinding  yaml

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu updated

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a ClusterRoleBinding to apply the ClusterRole `my-role` to the user. Assuming the user is `jane` below is an example. The problem in this approach is you need to keep updating it as and when new users gets onboarded.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: namespace-reader
subjects:
# You can specify more than one "subject"
- kind: User
  name: jane # "name" is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  # "roleRef" specifies the binding to a Role / ClusterRole
  kind: ClusterRole #this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: my-role # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

An alternative and better approach would be to restrict all authenticated users from creating namespace using below ClusterRoleBinding. Since we are applying the ClusterRole to the group `system:authenticated` and every user who is successfully authenticated is placed into this group automatically by kubernetes, no user except admin user will be able to create namespace.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: namespace-reader
subjects:
# You can specify more than one "subject"
- kind: Group
  name: system:authenticated
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  # "roleRef" specifies the binding to a Role / ClusterRole
  kind: ClusterRole #this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: my-role # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Since admin user is part of a set of admin groups it will be possible to create namespace as admin user.